# Sending params to the next_page after the logout

Tags: python, django, authentication

I want to have my users redirected back to the home page after logout. But I'd like to display a "logged out successfully" message in addition to the regular page.

I got the logging out and redirection working:

```
'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/portal/home'}
```

But I can't seem to find a way to send some information to the homepage through the logout view. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry if it's a noobie's question, it's my first django site. :P

Comment: What about adding a $_GET parameter, which will indicate to /portal/home/ that a logout just occurred? /portal/home/ can then display a message if that parameter exists. Does something like 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/portal/home/?logout=true' } work?

Comment: Instead of trying to do this in the URL, why don't you do it in the actual `logout` view code?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the messaging framework built into Django. Seems to fit your needs for this problem.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 0):

In your views

```
def my_logout(request):
  logout(request)
  msg="logged out"
  return render_to_response('portal/home',{'check':msg})
```

In your home.html write

```
{{check}}
```